# Google analytics4 user analytics snapshot

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Is it possible to access information like this but outside of real-time tab? Ideally what I want is to see a user journey path - the center image - for each of our users at this level of detail.
Specifically -when I click on view_item I can also bring up the properties of the item. This is a level of detail that is **deeper** than what I can access via the "Analysis" tab which only records the top line event - when I click on view_item in analysis that's all I get whereas here I can also see the properties of the event

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programing related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Dennis, Have you found any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could see the user's event activity is to [export the data to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) and filter it with the proper user_id with SQL.